# Android Google Cloud Messaging onMessage Intent returns null

Tags: android, android-intent, google-cloud-messaging

When I'm sending data without the letters å,ä and ö via the Google Cloud Messaging to my device everything works fine. But when I tested sending a message with å, ä an ö the app crashes. The logcat is the following:

```
10-08 13:17:28.821: E/AndroidRuntime(8148): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[GCMIntentService-460133591043-2]
10-08 13:17:28.821: E/AndroidRuntime(8148): Process: com.pingchat.app, PID: 8148
10-08 13:17:28.821: E/AndroidRuntime(8148): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-08 13:17:28.821: E/AndroidRuntime(8148):     at com.pingchat.app.GCMIntentService.onMessage(GCMIntentService.java:61)
10-08 13:17:28.821: E/AndroidRuntime(8148):     at com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService.onHandleIntent(GCMBaseIntentService.java:223)
10-08 13:17:28.821: E/AndroidRuntime(8148):     at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
10-08 13:17:28.821: E/AndroidRuntime(8148):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-08 13:17:28.821: E/AndroidRuntime(8148):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-08 13:17:28.821: E/AndroidRuntime(8148):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

I've tried to find ways to decode the intent "data" but with no success, is there any way to fix this? A try and catch would only print the stackrace.

`GCMIntentService.java:61` is

```
String message = data.getStringExtra("message");
```

Payload that I'm trying to send:

```
{
  "k": "0fba39e3-f38f-41b4-823b-c802180bc260",
  "d": "APA91bFtShoLXvvzwMh2tUaLlaAzB4ossHu7zUN2rp9S7Dtxurw86k9DvHR5FEN7VQAPWsW0yePAWFjNbVEd4A7UaYQffdSsl6Lz2SkcuXX511Qd4txo1GgEF6C3Ho46ibMRSdwRGGKdAnIZD4-cUQaeibV1pcGGuQ",
  "m": "message",
  "f": "root",
  "c": "Tjo, finns dunderöö"
}
```

GCMIntentService.java$OnMessage:

```
@Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent data) {
        String message = data.getStringExtra("message");
}
```

Comment: what is the line of code in GCMIntentService.java on line number 61 ?

Comment: @user2450263 I've updated the question, check it again

Comment: `GCMBaseIntentService` has been deprecated for over a year. You might consider switching to the new API from the Play Services SDK and using `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` and an `IntentService`, per [the current documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html).

Comment: @TimLilleSkuttBillström check what is the variable name in which you are passing the value contained in the push message from server, there might not be a "message" in the payload at all

Comment: @user2450263 I've checked several times, it must have something to do with encoding which makes the GCM set the intent to null I guess.

Comment: can you edit the question with adding the payload and GCMIntentService.java from opening of the class till line 61

Comment: @user2450263 The class is right big, I added the onMessage-method that's causing the problem with the intent

Answer (score 3):

Try with:

```
 String message = data.getExtras().getString("message");
```

instead of

```
 String message = data.getStringExtra("message");
```

Comment: Still the same problem when I'm sending å, ä or ö in the payload. Otherwise both lines work